# Fed up of Server Admin - Want career change guidance

Tags: untagged

I am SA in top level MNC and what I liked turned out to be my most disliked. I feel that I am capable of doing more than what I am doing at present. This 1 hour , 2 hour SLA is not my kind. I wanna get a better life.. The rotational shift is also something I am hating these days. Awkward shifts and too many process to follow.

I have 3 years of Experience. I dont wanna waste this 3 yrs of experience I wanna get into OS developer or kind of so that this three years of experience is not wasted !!

Please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Become a consultant for Mid-Sized businesses (or an admin for one). Large businesses are full of bureaucracy, it kills all the fun of the job. Small businesses frequently have crazy owners and crazy small budgets (while demanding enterprise functionality).

As always, don't take one company's bad experience to be the rule for all companies. Every place I've worked is different, if you know what you enjoy doing, you just have to find a place that lets you do it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you ever like your job at a point in time?  Or did things change suddenly?
Have you tried talking to your manager about things?  Your manager might be willing to make reasonable changes to make your life better.

But if you really want to change jobs, it shouldnt be too hard for you.  Hit the books, study up, and learn about development!  Your NetAdmin skills will augment your developer skills so nothing is wasted.
Plus this experience is good in you gauging what kind of job you want to have in the future.  Its just a matter of shifting to that new job.

Good luck!